# Math equation won't be read. Why is this?

Tags: c

Sorry for not adding the whole code. Dumb mistake on my part.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    float celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin, interval;
    int c, f, k;
    char temp;

    printf("which temperature is being input? (C,F,K) ");
    scanf("%s", &temp);

    if(temp == 'c') {
        printf("enter a starting temperature");
        scanf("%f", &celcius);
        fahrenheit=celcius*9/5+32;
        kelvin=celcius+273.2;
        printf("%f, %f, %f", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
        }

        else if(temp == 'f') {
        printf("Please enter a starting temperature");
        scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
        celcius=fahrenheit-32*5/9;
        kelvin=fahrenheit-32*5/9+273.2;
        printf("%f, %f, %f", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
           }

           else if(temp == 'k') {
            printf("enter a starting temperature");
                scanf("%f", &kelvin);
                fahrenheit=kelvin-273*1.8+32;
                celcius=kelvin-273.2;
                printf("%f, %f, %f", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
            }
}
```

So it asks for what temperature is being input and the starting temperature but why isn't it calculating the math equation?

Comment: You need to say what happens.

Comment: c, f, k .. come from where?

Comment: What are `c`, `f` and `k`? Did you perhaps mean to print `celcius`, `fahrenheit` and `kelvin`?

Comment: Please show a complete program. Given that `temp == 'c'` compiles, presumably `temp` is of type `char` -- which means that although `scanf("%s", &temp)` passes the right types, it will clobber memory immediately after `temp`. http://sscce.org/

Comment: I am sorry. I am new to this. c, f, and k are all int values and the rest are similar to this piece of code. I realized that I made a dumb mistake and assigned an int value with a float. @KeithThompson

Comment: `s/celcius/celsius/g`, by the way

Comment: Assigning an `int` value to a `float` isn't *necessarily* a mistake. But your complete program, with any `#include` directives and the declaration of `main`, and most importantly the declarations of all the variables you're using, should be just a few lines longer than what you've already shown us. Please update your question, copy-and-pasting your entire program, so we can see what you're actually doing.  See http://sscce.org/ for some good guidelines.

Comment: @KeithThompson I just posted the entire program.

Comment: Your prompt asks for `(C,F,K)`, but you check for lower case letters. Some of your calculations are incorrect. Due to operator precedence, `fahrenheit-32*5/9` is equivalent to `fahrenheit-17`; you want `(fahrenheit-32.0)*5.0/9.0`. All your constants should be floating-point: `32.0`, not `32`, etc. And the correct offset for Kelvin is `-273.15`; you use `-273.2` in some places and `-273` in another.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes I am just experimenting with how to do all of this. Your fahrenheit example really helped! I set the kelvin to 273.2 just because I wanted to get rid of all the extra numbers that came out in the output. for example it would come out as 543.000000. However this didn't work and I just forgot to change it back lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is calculating the math equations

```
fahrenheit=celcius*9/5+32;
kelvin=celcius+273.15;
```

but you are not printing it.
Try this

```
printf("%f, %f, %f", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
```

And do not forget to change `scanf("%s", &temp);` to

```
scanf(" %c", &temp);  
temp = tolower(temp); // include <ctype.h> header
```

or better to place

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != `\n` && c != EOF);
```

after `scanf(" %c", &temp);`. This will eat up all the character other than the first character of the input.

As per OP's comment;

> How can I do it so that the Temperature name appears on top of the temperature?

```
printf("celcius \tfahrenheit \tkelvin);  
printf("%5f\t%5f\t%5f", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
```

Comment: Yes this is right. Very sorry. New to programming and this website so I do feel like an idiot right now. Thank you! Also a quick question. How can I do it so that the Temperature name appears on top of the temperature?

Comment: Thank you very much @haccks This was the answer I needed!

Comment: Your welcome. But do not forget to read the [link](http://sscce.org/) given by Keith Thompson.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show how you defined your variable `temp`, but it is extremely dangerous to read a string in this way. If `temp` is a character, then pointing to the address of it and treating it as a string is asking for trouble. For sure you will have a `'\0'` written to the location right after `temp`, and if the user inputs more than a single character the damage they could do is even larger.

You can read a single character with a `getc` call:

```
temp = getc(stdin);
```

I would recommend that you make sure it is lower case - since you are comparing with `c`:

```
temp = lower(getc(stdin));
```

Then obviously, when you print out a variable, you must print out the one you computed. You compute `celcius`, etc - but your print statement is

```
printf("%f, %f, %f", c, f, k);
```

`c`, `f`, and `k` may be valid variables - but they are not the ones you computed in the lines before. Replace the print statement with

```
printf("Celsius: %.1f; Fahrenheit: %.1f; Kelvin: %.1f\n", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
```

Or, if you want the name above the number:

```
printf("\tC\tF\tK\n\t%6.1f\t%6.1f\t%6.1f\n", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
```

Note the use of `\t` - the `tab` character - to get things to align (approximately) and the format specifier `%4.1f` to say "number in a field width of 6, with one significant digit after the decimal".

One more note - it's `Celsius`, not `celcius`. But that is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is calculating, but you're printing the wrong variables.  Try replacing c, f, and k with celsius, fahrenheit, and kelvin in the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be consistent in your variable names, you can't mix them up like you are.

Because you are calculating it like so:

```
fahrenheit=celcius*9/5+32;
kelvin=celcius+273.15;
```

However this line is not printing it out, since you have the wrong variables:

```
printf("%f, %f, %f", c, f, k);
```

Change that to the proper variable name and type like so:

```
printf("%f, %f, %f", celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin);
```